# Is it possible to use output from raw_input() as a new file name?

Tags: python-2.7, createfile, raw-input

I'm wondering if it's possible to use the return from `raw_input()`to create a file name?

What I have so far:

```
import os
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
Tk().withdraw()
ttnum=str(raw_input('Please enter ticket number: '))
ttnum
filename=askopenfilename()
abspath = os.path.abspath(filename) 
dname = os.path.dirname(abspath)    
os.chdir(dname)                     
f=open(filename)
contents=f.read()
file_len(filename)
file_scan(filename)
```

Portion of code that calls ttnum:

```
def file_len(filename):
#Count the number of line in the Text File
    f1 = open(("WiFi Logs report for tt " + ttnum,'w'))
    with open(filename) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass     
    f1.write('Total number of lines in file: ' + str(i+1) + '\n' + '\n')
    f1.close()  

def file_scan(filename):
#List of issues to Scan For
    f1 = open(("WiFi Logs report for tt " + ttnum,'a'))
```

I can enter input no problem (in this case 12345), but once it hits the code, I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "M:\WiFi Log Scanner\WiFi_Log_Scanner.py", line 153, in <module>
    file_len(filename)
  File "M:\WiFi Log Scanner\WiFi_Log_Scanner.py", line 4, in file_len
    f1 = open(("WiFi Logs report for tt " + ttnum,'w'))
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, tuple found
```

I thought that the str() at the start would ensure that it is, well, a string and not a tuple?

Any insight would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove a layer of parentheses from `open(("WiFi Logs report for tt " + ttnum,'a'))`:

```
open("WiFi Logs report for tt " + ttnum,'a')
```

With extra parentheses, you pass *one* argument to `open`, and this argument is a *tuple*: a pair of values, which is not what `open` expects for its first argument.

A side note (unrelated to your error): you don't have to `chdir` before you read a file (and your actual code only works when `filename` is already absolute, which the result of `tk_getOpenFile` *is*. `chdir` doesn't help anything here). And *when* `chdir` is necessary, it's error-prone (it introduces hidden state) and thread-unsafe.

Comment: Cool, got it creating a file, just a file of unspecified type. Will open fine once you select what program to use, but think I'll go back to using just a plain string rather than a tuple for the time being. Thanks though, can keep that in mind and mess around with it, see if I can get something working.

With regards to the `chdir`, if I don't have this in the report that's generated goes into the root folder that I pull the file from rather than the same folder. I want it in the same folder for convenience sake. Unless I've completely missed what you're saying? :)

Comment: When you already have `dname`, use something like `os.path.join(dname,'WiFi Logs green frogs hot dogs')` to get a *full* path name for the output file, and open it using this full pathname.

Comment: EDIT: Found if I add .txt manually when entering in the filename in the raw_input, it creates a text file. That should do for a work-around.

Thanks again!